# How to read binary file from google bucket in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, binaryfiles, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

Is there any best approach to read binary file from google bucket, I'm trying below code but when I'm trying to read the file from bucket and extract I'm facing illegal offset issue.

I have uploaded binary file which has extension .tx manually under fabriccerts bucket. I have to read the file in cloud function and extract the same using fabrclient module.

Below is the function to read the file from the bucket.

```
 const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage();
    async function getFileContent(fileName, bucketName) {
      const myBucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
      const file = myBucket.file(fileName);
      const content = await file.download();
      return content;
    };
```

Below are the statements from the cloud function which I'm trying to extract the binary file using fabric-client module.

```js
const Client = require('fabric-client');
    let envelope_bytes = await storage_util.getFileContent("channel.tx", "fabriccerts");
   console.log("file data" + envelope_bytes);
    let config_update = client.extractChannelConfig(envelope_bytes);
```

```
Error: Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
Illegal offset: 0 <= 1 (+1) <= 1
```

Is there any specific way to read the binary file? Do we need convert the file after downloading?

I have tried the same in ubuntu machine storing the channel.tx file in the local directory which is working fine and displaying below after reading the file:

```
    �
                                                                                                                                                               ����"     mychannel�
    �
            mychannel;)

    Application

    Org1MSP

    Org2MSP

    Consortium��

    Application�

    Org2MSP

    Org1MSP&
    Capabilities



    V1_4_2Admins""
    WritersAdmins""
    Admins

    AdminsAdmins""
    ReadersAdmins*Admins"

    Consortium
    SampleConsortium
```

But when i store the same file in the bucket and the read the file it is displaying below data:

```
    �  ����" mychannel� � mychannel;) Application Org1MSP� Org2MSP� Consortium��� Application� Org2MSP� Org1MSP�& Capabilities V1_4_2�Admins"" Writers  WritersAdmins"" Admins AdminsAdmins"" Readers  ReadersAdmins*Admins" Consortium SampleConsortium
```

Error logs:

```
RangeError: Illegal offset: 0 <= 1 (+1) <= 1 at ByteBuffer.module.exports.ByteBufferPrototype.readVarint32 (/srv/node_modules/bytebuffer/dist/bytebuffer-node.js:1540:23) at Message.ProtoBuf.Reflect.MessagePrototype.decode (/srv/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:3237:36) at Function.Message.decode (/srv/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/protobufjs/dist/protobuf.js:2952:37) at Client.extractChannelConfig (/srv/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:660:42) at Object.exports.createChannel (/srv/chainmanagement/channel-management.js:36:30) at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

**Do we need to raise a bug with google ?**

Comment: Did you try to use the ["createReadStream"](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createReadStream) method from the official API library? Also the error message recommends to "inspect logs for termination reason", could you share the full log entry with us in order to give us more information? Also please take a look at this [Github issue](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/issues/441) regarding the `Illegal offset` message.

Comment: I have used createreadstream but still facing the same issue. Both the files printing the same data on screen but not sure what exact change required to make it readable.

Comment: Hello, can you follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs) documentation and share with us the results?

Comment: @chainicko I have followed the same document initially. You can compare the sample code.

Comment: ok good. The error indicates to check the logs can you share with us the logs? thanks

Comment: @chainicko I have already updated the logs. Please check

Comment: error logs already added in the question @chainicko

Comment: There are logs from Stackdriver from the Logging menu (console) choose GCS Bucket. You should have better logs there and not just the error. Also from the error I can understand that the function terminated. My assumption is that the first part is working correctly and you can read the data, please test it and confirm that. If yes, the issue is in the second part when you are extracting the binary file. Also you mentioned that it’s working on Ubuntu locally so please confirm that you can read the files for the data in order to be sure where the issue is when you are using GCP.

Comment: i have even tried placing the file in the local directory in google cloud function which is working fine. As you mentioned there is no issue in reading the file, but issue is when extracting the file when i read the file from bucket. I cant see the bucket name fabriccerts under GCS Bucket, do i need to explicitly enable the logs for the bucket?

Comment: Since we are sure that the issue is on Cloud Function I think there is no need to investigate further the Bucket but the logs from the Cloud Function. So can you share with us the logs from the Stackdriver for the Cloud Function?

Comment: @chainicko I have already shared log details from the stack driver. please verify.

Comment: [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam/issues/234) could be related, as from the Illegal offset message.

Comment: Error is same but error cause is different @Artemis